# FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter doesn't working

Tags: firebaseui

I put this in dependencies compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2' and i can't use firebaseindexrecycleradapter,i get message Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter'... anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

```
enter code here
```